# I want to place a circle in the center of the menu element

Tags: html, css

I am practicing CSS.

I learned to place circle in the center using `position:absolute`.

I want to place a blue small circle on the `menu` element, but it is not placed on the `.menu`.

I'm having a hard time solving this. I uploaded an image.

```css
#wrap .menu {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap .one {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <h1>상단</h1>
  </header>

  <content>

    <aside>
      <h2>좌측단</h2>

      <div>
        <p class="menu">menudan</p>
        <div>
          <p class="one"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </aside>

    <section>
      <h2>본문단</h2>
      <p>컨텐츠1</p>
      <p>컨텐츠2</p>

    </section>

  </content>

  <footer>
    <p>하단 카피단</p>
  </footer>
```

[image]

Comment: What is a menudan?

Comment: @Geshode, the blue square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an `absolute` positioned element positions itself to the nearest parent with a position set. You need to add `position: relative` to the `.menu` element.

I changed your HTML a bit, since the `.one` element was not a child of the `.menu` element, which would make it difficult to position correctly.

```css
#wrap .menu {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap .one {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <h1>상단</h1>
  </header>

  <content>

    <aside>
      <h2>좌측단</h2>

      <div>
        <div class="menu">menudan
          <div class="one"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </aside>

    <section>
      <h2>본문단</h2>
      <p>컨텐츠1</p>
      <p>컨텐츠2</p>

    </section>

  </content>

  <footer>
    <p>하단 카피단</p>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `border-radius:50%;` in menudan div

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this css code can do the work:

```css
#wrap {
  display: table;
}
#wrap .menu {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#wrap .one {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```